# Unable to boot Windows 8.1 with GRUB, reboots everytime

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, grub2

I have two HD drives, one with Linux Mint Debian Edition, the other with Windows 8.1. I was able to boot both of them using GRUB, with no problems. Yesterday I tried to boot Windows after almost 3 months of not using it. The loading screen appeared (with the blue Windows icon), but shortly after the PC rebooted. When I tried it again, the message "Loading Automatic Repair" appeared, and it rebooted once again. This kept going forever (normal boot->reboot->automatic repair->reboot). No other messages were shown.

I thought that maybe the Windows installation had become magically corrupted or something, so I reinstalled it from scratch. I installed all programs, and every available update, everything worked. But then, after booting Mint and updating GRUB, I was met by the same error once again. I read that the Fast Boot option could give problems, so I disabled it, to no avail. Right now, the only way I have to start Windows is by telling the BIOS to boot into the HD it is in. Choosing it from GRUB does not work.

My PC is from 2010 and does not have UEFI or Secure Boot support (thankfully!).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why thankfully if it did support UEFI you wouldn't have this problem

Comment: @Ramhound I have another PC and two laptops with UEFI and I can't think of a bigger pain. It took me several days to get a Linux installed on those. Anyway, I think this problem has to do with GRUB, as I can boot Windows normally by choosing its HD.

Comment: "But then, after booting Mint and updating GRUB" <-- I think the "Updating GRUB" is likely to blame. Try to figure out what changed when it updated and see if there's something you can fix there.

Comment: @MarkAllen I have checked `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but the W8 entry seems in order (not that I am a GRUB expert, of course). Maybe W8 is expecting some special boot parameter that only its official bootloader gives...

Comment: @user3497081 Ok, so then what grub.cfg look like on a working system, does it look different?

Comment: @MarkAllen Thanks, that helped me solve it. I compared a working W7 entry from other computer entry with the W8 one.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. The GRUB menu entry for Windows 8.1 had this line:

```
drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
```

After commenting it, Windows now boots correctly from GRUB. I don't know why `update-grub` included it, though (hd0 is the first HD drive, where Mint is, while Windows is in hd1, the second drive).

EDIT: the file I am talking about is `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Entries of Windows systems can usually be found at the end. Also, don't forget that this file is automatically generated by GRUB, and that it will be overwritten every time `update-grub` is run!

Comment: Updating this file directly is not recommended. Instead, update the templates in `/etc/grub.d` or wherever they’re located on your system.

Comment: Same scenario, win8.1 died while booting after I reinstalled grub. This solution helped. thx

Comment: Had same problem after splitting my OSes between a SSD and a HDD. As @DanielB recommends, instead of editing `grub.cfg` edit the file `/etc/grub.d/30_OS-prober`. Just comment the same line, `drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}`